# Local notification для геолокации

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Врем привет!

Есть геолокация, но она не работает, когда приложение свернуто. Есть ли какие-то примеры, где пушки для геолокации стреляют правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, не знаю, у гугла хотябы спрашивайте для начала: [вот пример работы гугла на стеке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15592648/887325).